# Rails 3 and Rspec 2 namespaced controller problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, rspec, rspec2

I;m trying to write a spec that tests a controller that is namespaced, let's call it `Admin::FooController`. My spec is called `admin_foo_controller_spec.rb`. In the spec, I'm trying to write a very basic spec to see if it can retrieve an action of a controller.

```
describe "GET 'index'" do
  it "should be successful" do
    get 'index'
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

But instead I get an error:

```
 Failure/Error: get 'index'
 No route matches {:controller=>"admin/foo"}
```

For another action, I have basically the same test, and I get that the response is not successful. In the actual webapp, I can access these urls fine. One thing I should mention is that this isn't a RESTful resource (it makes no sense as one) so it's really just a group of related administrative actions, so in my routes.rb it's basically like

```
namespace :admin do
  scope "foo" do
    match "action1" => "foo#action1"
    match "action2" => "foo#action2"
    match "/index" => "foo#settings"
    match "settings" => "foo#settings"
  end
end
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? It seems like namespacing is asking for trouble with rails, especially for a novice like me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your route your have no index action in you Foo controller try to get 'settings'

```
describe "GET 'index'" do
  it "should be successful" do
    get 'settings'
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

In a controller spec you need define the action of your controller not the real route. You try the routes in a integration test.